# two sites, one database with laravel sail

Tags: php, database, laravel, docker

I have two sites which run in separate containers through laravel sail. I edited the `.env` files to assign different ports, so that they can run concurrently. One listens to ports 80/3306 and the other ports 4000/3310.

Both sites work, but the database with port 3310 refuses the connection when laravel tries to access it or if I try running migrations. I can connect to the db through DBeaver so I know the database is there.  The error it gives is `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`

I want both sites to use the same database, the one on port 3306, I put the corresponding credentials into the `.env`. The first site connects to the database(these two are in the same container), but the second site (which is in a separate container) is denied access, just like with its own database, but this time the error is `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user`

The `docker-compose.yml` files are unchanged, I only changed ports in the `.env` files

all docker containers are on the same network (sail)

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, my experience with docker is limited to using it through sail, I would be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction

I tried some suggestions from stack overflow, like changing the password, recreating the database manually and changing the database host but nothing worked

here is the `docker-compose.yml` of the container that fails to connect to the database

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.0/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mariadb
    mariadb:
        image: 'mariadb:10'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmariadb:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
          retries: 3
          timeout: 5s
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmariadb:
        driver: local
```

Comment: Can you post your docker-compose.yml

Comment: you don't need to change the DB port you should be able to use the same db with both services as long as you only have one db service running

Comment: @PeterDavis added

Comment: @apokryfos so I should remove the db service from one of the two containers?

Comment: I think each service under the services of your docker-compose is its own container so I think you could consider moving one of your laravel apps to the other docker-compose.yml to ensure when your run the containers they all start together rather than having to compose them individually

Comment: @apokryfos hey that actually sounds like a good idea, I will give it a go!